# Factor groups and Burnside's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm supposed to find the number of orbits in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ under the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1,3,5,6)$ of $S_8$. I would have very much appreciated an explanation to this exercise since I am not very good with factor groups or Burnside's lemma.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

$\{1,3,5,6\}$ is an orbit by the definition of cycle. The other elements are not moved and so the orbits are $$\{1,3,5,6\}, \{2\}, \{4\}, \{7\}, \{8\}$$